# Automatically create and set WordPress featured image from first gallery shortcode ID

Tags: wordpress, image, gallery, wordpress-featured-image

Does anyone know how to Automatically create and set the featured image from the first ID in the gallery shortcode?

Example: [gallery order="DESC" ids="5428,5427,5421,5420"]

I was thinking something like this:

```
        // Automatically set featured image from gallery shortode
        function set_featured_image_from_gallery() {
            global $post;
            $post_id = $post->ID;
            $has_thumbnail = get_the_post_thumbnail($post_id);
              if ( !$has_thumbnail ) {
                $post_content = $post->post_content;
                preg_match('/\[gallery.*ids=.(.*).\]/', $post_content, $ids);
                $images_id = explode(",", $ids[1]);
                if ( $image_id ) {
                  set_post_thumbnail( $post_id, $images_id );
                }
              }
        }
        add_action( 'save_post_property',  'set_featured_image_from_gallery' );
```

Comment: Set the featured image **of what**?  Where is this shortcode inserted? Where do you want the "featured image" to appear? This will almost certainly require theme modifications, depending on your answers.

Comment: Hi cale_b,  This would set the featured image of a post in WordPress. It would appear in the post. We have a custom theme so modifying the theme is ok.

Comment: I was thinking something like this -- I added new code to my first question on top.